Avoiding a race conditions between two coroutine operations
I have two operations that are done using corroutines. Fetching from a preferences Datastore, and making an api (retrofit) call. The network call is dependent on knowing what type of Unit the user prefers (Fahrenheit, Celsius), so I need to get this data first before launching the network call.
I am not sure if I am creating a race condition here or if calling the suspend function like shown below is always going to follow the correct call order.
private suspend fun getUnits(): Units {
    var openWeatherUnits: Units = Units.FAHRENHEIT // default
    // Get Units
    dataStore.readStringDataStore(UNITS_KEY).first().let { units ->
        if (units != null) {
            println("units: $units")
            openWeatherUnits = Units.valueOf(units)
        }
    }
    return openWeatherUnits
}

private fun getWeatherData() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val units = getUnits()

        // Make API call
        val response = apiService.getCurrentWeather(
            BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_KEY,
            units.value
        )

    }
}


what is the problem you are facing now?

@Sasi Kumar the call order seems correct to me. But I am not 100% sure if I created a race condition with this code. Or this is the correct way to call two coroutines when order matters.

@KennySexton - Code within a coroutine is by default executed sequentially

seems your code is fine.even getUnits() function return some default value when the race condition. so its not affected

When you call the funstion getWeatherData() it launches a coroutine in viewModelScope. Internally suspend function getUnits() is called which will pause execution of the coroutine until it finishes (as mentioned by @Leviathan).
Here the statement 'val units = getUnits()' will suspend 'getWeatherData' execution until 'getUnits' result is received. Once received it will go ahead.
So no race conditions here.

"[...] so there are two coroutines right now" -- That's not true, there is only one coroutine, the one created by viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO). getUnits is not a coroutine, it is just a suspend function, meaning, it needs to be called when already in a coroutine. Calling a suspend function doesn't create a new coroutine. And since there are no additional coroutines you also don't have any race conditions. Wrong premise, correct conclusion.

Thank you @Leviathan, updating the same in answer as well.

The wording is still misleading, neither getWeatherData nor val units = getUnits() suspends. The coroutine is what is suspended, and it gets suspended by the internals of first() (which we don't see here). But if that actually suspends the coroutine or not doesn't even matter. The only thing that matters is that getUnits() is called in the same coroutine as the rest of getWeatherData().

Your code will work perfectly fine, Api call will be made after the call getUnits() returns. But if you want to know how actually the problem can be generated here. I give you the example
// Note: Avoid this type of coding,
// this will launch two coroutines running at the same time.
// Here your API can be called even before getUnits() finishes.
fun getWeatherData() {
    var units: Units = Units.FAHRENHEIT // default
    // getUnits() function call here
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        units = getUnits()
    }
    // Api call here, it will not wait for the above code to be finished
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val response = apiService.getCurrentWeather(
            BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_KEY,
            units.value
        )
    }
}

calling suspend functions in different coroutines can create the problem in your case. but here you are right.
In sort, If you have 3 different suspend function and you want to execute them parallel your code could be
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { fun1() }
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { fun2() }
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { fun3() }

this is helpful if you want to call three different API at the same time which are total independent from each other,
But if you want call the suspend function one after other, you can write something like this. e.g. if you want to call fun2() first then fun3() and fun1() at last
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { 
    fun2() 
    fun3() // will be called after fun2() finished
    fun1() // will be called after fun1() finished
}

Note: You are right with your code, my code is only for information. do not consider this as the solution of your question

I fixed some wording issues in your answer, please review that it still conveys what you wanted to say.

Okay Thanks @Leviathan
